# How to covert ALL "double" values into "single" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

In my matlab workspace I have structs, cells and variables . In need to convert all "double" type values into "single" type values.

For example from

```
4x33 double
```

I need to make it to

```
4x33 single
```

I have already used such piece of code:

```
s = whos;
disp(s)
for i = 1:length(s)
      if strcmp(s(i).class,'double')
          name = s(i).name;
          disp(name);
          assignin('base', name, single(evalin('base', name)));
      end
end
```

And it works fine for variables which are stored in my workspace, but issue is that it cannot reach values which are stored in workspace in structs.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Converting everything to single is not a good idea. MATLAB’s natural type is double, computation with singles is awkward at best, and many functions will not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to convert a double to single is

`b=single(a)`.

You can use `single` as a structfun:

```
a.c=5;
b=structfun(@single,a)
```